# Automating Database Connection

Tags: postgresql, shell, ssh, automation, putty

For a homework, I have a few steps I have to go through every single time I want to connect to the database and it's becoming a really annoying and time-wasting act.

I've already automated part of it. However, my latest attempt at automating the last few commands hasn't been successful.

Initially, I've set up a shortcut to a `PuTTy` terminal:

1. Create new Shortcut
2. Select `"C:\Program Files\PuTTY"` as the entry point (`Start in`)
3. Enter `"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" <MY_USERNAME>@arcade.iro.umontreal.ca -pw <MY_PASSWORD>` as the `Target`

Then after double-clicking this shortcut, I entered these two lines (to create and then execute a bash script):

```
echo "psql -h postgres && \c ift2935 && set search_path to inscriptions_devoir;" > sql.sh
. sql.sh
```

Eventually, my goal would be to simply be able to write `. sql.sh` after opening my shortcut to be all set up and ready to go (and actually, maybe even *that* can be automatized somehow with the shortcut?). However, **as it is, my shell script only runs the `psql -h postgres` command**, which successfully launches `PostGreSQL`.

My question is:

**How do I get the two other commands (`\c ift2935` and `set search_path to inscriptions_devoir;`) to automatically run inside PostGreSQL?**

---

EDIT:

Forgot to mention: after the first command of my script executes, I can then type `\q` to leave `PostGreSQL` and then the terminal outputs this:

```
-bash: c: command not found
```

Which, I think, indicates that the terminal interrupts its current process to actually run `PostGreSQL` and, on exit, it resumes the script, moving onto the second command, which fails because `\c` means nothing as a shell command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While connected to the database, run:

```
ift2935=> ALTER ROLE <MY_USERNAME> SET search_path TO inscriptions_devoir;
```

This is your database user. Unless `PGUSER` is set, this should be the same as your operating system user, but you can always find it with `SELECT current_user;`.

Then the setting will automatically be active the next time you connect.

In your shell script, change the call to

```
psql -h postgres -d ift2935
```

Alternatively, and slightly better in my opinion, is the following, more complicated procedure:

- Edit the file `.bash_profile` in your home directory and add

  ```
  export PGHOST=postgres
  export PGDATABASE=ift2935
  ```

  Then disconnect and reconnect (this file is executed when you start a login shell).
- Instead of running `. sql.sh`, simply type `psql`, which is less cumbersome.

Off topic: It is widely held that industriousness is the motor of progress. Nothing could be farther from the truth. Laziness is the mother of invention, specifically laziness paired with curiosity. If you plan to go into the computer engineering business, I promise you a bright future.

Comment: `psql -h postgres -d ift2935` indeed did bring me one step closer the my goal! However, `ALTER DATABASE ift2935 SET search_path TO inscriptions_devoir;`, as I kind of was expecting, returned `ERROR: must be owner of database ift2935`.

Comment: Additionally, would you know if there is a way to tell me `Shortcut` to automatically run those shell commands (as text, or as the execution of the bash script I've created)?

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE` and `ALTER ROLE` are persistent. You only need to run them once, and the setting is set for ever.

Comment: `ALTER ROLE` worked out perfectly! Thank you so much. Feel free to answer my additional question (from my last comment, just above).

Comment: You would run `psql ... -c "commands go here"`. I hope I didn't praise you prematurely, you should be curious enough to look into the `psql` documentation page.

Comment: Hum, what I meant was that double-clicking the shortcut would automatically make the call to the bash script so that I wouldn't have to type `. sql.sh` afterward. Your solution seems to be about modifying the bash script itself which doesn't prevent me from having to execute it manually through the command line.

Comment: And, lastly, I have [this annoying popup](https://i.snag.gy/cvEdm8.jpg) which I would love to suppress (basically automatically ACCEPTING when received after using my specific shortcut).

Comment: You cannot get rid of the pop-up if the server changes its identity every time. C'mon, typing `psql` isn't that hard. But there is nothing that keeps you from adding it to your `.bash_profile`. Be creative!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try using the pgpass file.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html